# SQL Server 2005 Database Encryption - Master Key not staying open

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Here is my scenario:

1. I restored a database R to a QA SQL Server and renamed to to Rtest. There is another instance of database R on the server.
2. I ran the following commands to enable encryption:

   ```
   OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ABC'
   RESTORE MASTER KEY FROM FILE = 'ThePath' 

   DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'DEF'
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'GHI'
   ```

If I connect to the database as the SysAdmin I am able to decrypt the column that is encrypted. queries work just fine.

If I connect to the database as a local user I get the following error:

> Msg 15581, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.

While logged in as the local user I run the following:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ABC'
```

I am able to run queries for the connection but once I open up a new connection I am back to getting the error.

The only way I have been able to consistently run the queries is to run the following command every time access to the encrypted column is desired:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ABC'
```

Basically I have to do the following each time I want to select, update, or insert to the table:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ABC'

select EncryptedColumn from TableA where x = 2
```

I am trying to figure out why I have to keep opening up the Master Key every time.  Usually I just run the command once and then that is it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the DMK into the System database:

OPEN MASTER KEY
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '@ this is a 123 strong password';

ALTER MASTER KEY
ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;

This will allow SQL server to auto open the Database master key automatically when needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186937(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Is there any way to check if a service account has access to use the SMK? I read that updating sql service account using the services (rather than the config manager) results in the new service account to not have access to the SMK.